# Disable HTTPS on Wikipedia

Tags: google-chrome, https

Wikipedia loads over HTTPS by default on my machine. This makes page loads take a long time, so I'd like for Wikipedia to default to HTTP instead. How can I do this? I am surfing from a home internet connection and using Google Chrome browser, with no extensions installed.

Comment: What browser are you using, with what plugins? Are you surfing from home, or any other place?

Comment: What if you *type* the URL, without `https://`?

Comment: It automatically gets converted to an `https://` link

Comment: I have noticed that HTTPS actually is enforced the way described for articles in Russian but is not for articles in other languages. I am curious about how to switch to plain HTTP for Russian articles too.

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* you have no extensions installed? Does the same thing happen in Incognito mode as well? Here are some things you can try:

1. Try clearing your browser history, cache, cookies etc. completely, close Chrome, reopen and click the following link (or enter it manually): http://en.wikipedia.org
2. Open the following page in Chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

   [image: 1]

   Under **Delete domain** enter *wikipedia.org* and for good measure *en.wikipedia.org* (or whichever localised version you use) and **Delete** them. Then follow step 1 above and see if it made any difference.